# flask-swagger IDs and returning an array of things

Tags: python, swagger

We're using flask-swagger to document our Flask/Python REST API.

In many cases, I return an `a_name`:

```
schema:
    id: a_name
    properties:
         first_name:
             type: string
             description: first name
         last_name:
             type: string
             description: last name
```

So, I define this once, and thereafter my endpoints only refer to the schema ID.  That is, if I put the following in a new endpoint:

```
schema:
    id: a_name
```

then swagger sucks in the previous definition of `a_name`. That's great.

However, in my 'get all' endpoint, I return an array of `a_name`. How can I show this in the swagger without copy/pasting the schema def for a single `a_name`?

EDIT: Here it is.

```
responses:
  200:
    description: a_names successfully retrieved
    schema:
        properties:
          names:
            type: array
            items:
                schema:
                    id: a_names
```

Which yields:

```
{
  "names": [
    {
      "first_name": "string",
      "last_name": "string",
    }
  ]
}
```